# Android, How can i set the fragment to display in the activity even closing the app?

Tags: android

Is there a way to save the fragment on change?Even after closing the app and open again the fragment will stay there

Comment: Do you mean saving the state? If so you can not restore an app's state after it's on destroy has been called. You can however save your fragment's information and then recreate it later with that data

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to save the variables you'll need the next time you open the app.
[Look at the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
    ...
    editor.commit();
}

protected void onCreate(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
    ...    
}
```

Comment: Does it apply to framelayout too? i have the code above replacing the framelayout using switch case it changes when i click on the item it change the display of my container which is the framelayout in my mainactivity but when i close the application and open it again the layout change again to its default